# How can I configure ImageMagick to not use any temporary files?

Tags: c++, perl, imagemagick, temporary-files, tmp

I'm trying to run ImageMagick without touching the filesystem: image data is read from memory/the network, and written back to a socket as a [blob](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Blob.html).

However, ImageMagick continually tries to write temp files, which either fill up my test system due to aborted/failed tests, or cause problems on systems with extremely slow disks: it's a weird constraint, but many of my conversion hosts are embedded-like systems with block devices that are *extremely* slow to respond to any operations, even `stat()`s.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a way to configure ImageMagick to not touch the disk during image processing?Assume that all required modules that ImageMagick will use have already been loaded, and that none of the ImageMagick functionality that farms processing out to subprocesses that talk to the filesystem will be used.
2. What are the side effects of doing this? I'm OK with processing that won't fit in memory failing, rather than falling back to the disks.

I'm converting using the C++ or Perl ImageMagick APIs, not the `convert` utility. If another binding has support for this, though, I'm fine switching platforms.

**What I've Tried**

- I've set the `MAGICK_TEMPORARY_PATH` to various places, including `/dev/null` on POSIX. `/dev/null` sometimes seems to work, but my target systems aren't POSIX, so I'm not sure if I can count on it. Rather than fooling the temp file management system, I'd prefer something that I can trust to disable the need for temp files in the first place.
- I've used the `registry:temporary-path` option, with similar results.
- Setting the various temporary path options to nonexistent/unusable locations (e.g. `/dev/null` or a non-writable location) often seems to result in temporary files being created in the directory from which my program is launched. If that directory is non-writable, I have seen temp files get created in the system `/tmp` directory even if the code was told not to use it. These seem to happen in exceptional cases (e.g. segfaulting/OOMing/`kill -9`'d situations), so I gather that files may be created in these places normally, but are usually cleaned up.

Comment: Is it possible to create a memory disk and put the /tmp there (between two consecutive launches you destroy the ram-disk, recreate/remount it again)? Failing that, is it possible to launch your program from a script which deletes /tmp once your app terminates?

Comment: The ramdisk option is possible; so is using and clearing `/dev/shm` or similar. Those both require the code to cope with previous hard-aborted (crashed, segfaulted, etc) runs leaving a mess, and subsequent runs having to clean it up, so it's not ideal.

Auto-cleaning /tmp doesn't achieve much, as the filesystem access still has to happen (and slow everything down) in the first place.

Comment: Take look at the full list of [environment variables](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php). Maybe try setting `MAGICK_DISK_LIMIT` to zero and increasing the `MAGICK_MEMORY_LIMIT`?

Comment: Increasing the memory limit seems to help somewhat, but I'm interested in preventing temp file usage in all cases--even if more memory is needed, a failure would be preferable.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to set `MAGICK_DISK_LIMIT=0` and `MAGICK_AREA_LIMIT`/`MAGICK_AREA_LIMIT` to a value larger than the maximum memory required by the program.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
BEGIN {
    $ENV{'MAGICK_DISK_LIMIT'  }='0';
    $ENV{'MAGICK_AREA_LIMIT'  }='1Mb';
    $ENV{'MAGICK_MEMORY_LIMIT'}='1Mb';
}

use Image::Magick;    
my $img = Image::Magick->new();
my $err = $img->Read('in.png');
die $err if $err;
```

If ImageMagick exceeds this memory limit it will die with a message like:

```
Exception 450: Memory allocation failed `in.png' @ error/png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1645 at ./imagemem.pl line 11.
```

You can view ImageMagick's default limits by running `identify -list resource`

Answer (score 0):

I had to increase the memory in the config file, when using the command line tools:

In **/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml:**

```
<!-- DEFAULT: <policy domain="resource" name="memory" value="256MiB"/> -->
<policy domain="resource" name="memory" value="1024MiB"/>
```

There was a discrepancy with versions: 8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu6.9 (Ubuntu 18.04) worked default without writing temporary files and with 256MiB, but with 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.2 (Ubuntu 20.04) I had to increase the memory as above.